# Getters in vuex is being called before actions

Tags: async-await, vuex, vuejs3

I am using vuex and in my setup I call dispatch then the getter.  When I refresh my page the getter always is called first and I am not sure how to change using async await so the getter only fires are the action is called.

Here is my setup in my .vue file

```
setup(props: any, context: any) {
    const store: any = useStore()
    store.dispatch('teams/getTeams')
    let teams = computed(() => store.getters['teams/teams']) as any;
}
```

Here is my actions.ts file

```
    import Http from "@/helpers/Http";
    
    export const actions = {
        async getTeams({ commit, dispatch}: any) {
            const http = new Http();
            const response = await http.get(`/api/teams`)
            commit('setTeams', response)
        }
    }

Here is the Http.ts


import axios from 'axios'

export default class Http {    
  async put(url: string, data: any) {
    const response = await axios.put(url, data)
    if(response.data){
      return response.data 
    }else{
      return response.status;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is mutations.ts

```
export const mutations = {
  setTeams(state: any, teams: any) {
    state.teams = teams
  }
}
```

Here is getters.ts

```
export const getters = {
  teams: (state: any): any => {
    console.log("In getters")
    return state.teams
  }
}
```

What do I change so the getters call is only fired after the dispatch call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actions are asynchronous. If you want to await for the action to be resolved you can use async await. Look this exemple (without composition API):

"component.vue"

```
methods: {
    async getTeam(){
       await this.$store.dispatch('teams/getTeams')
       let teams = computed(() => store.getters['teams/teams']) as any;
    }
}
```

If you want to catch the api response is possible to return it from action.

"component.vue"

```
methods: {
    async getTeam(){
       data = await this.$store.dispatch('teams/getTeams')
       ....
    }
}
```

Action exemple like "store/teams.js"

```
export const actions = {
   async getTeams(){
        const http = new Http();
        const response = await http.get(`/api/teams`)
        return response
   }
}
```